# how to fix this error with android studio 3,2

Tags: android

I am writing a project with two activities and I want that when I click on a button in the first Activity, it leads to the second Activity. And also when I click on a button in the second Activity, it leads me back to the first Activity. For this purpose, I have used `Intent` in Kotlin. But at runtime, when I click on the button in first activity, the app stops working. And the following error is displayed in the `logcat`:

> 1624-1637/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module.

And another error:

> E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: modem info is invalid:
>   ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0
>   mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}

My code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


      fun changeActivity(view: View){
          val addr = Intent(this@MainActivity, Main2Activity::class.java)
          startActivity(addr)
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried almost all of the solutions proposed in this stack overflow concerning other related questions but to no avail. Please can somebody look into my problem? I'm blocked with this issue